Moveit2 Cartesian Movement along y axis of tool frame instead of world frame

I can move the UR robot Cartesian by using Moveit2 script. There is a sample code UR robot is moving as a Cartesian movement along z axis with respect to world or base frame. However, I unfortunately could not find solution that robot will be moved as a Cartesian movement along y axiss with respect to axis 6 frame instead of world frame. You can image that my camera is attached to robot that is why the robot should move along camera frame regardless world frame.
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // Initialize ROS and create the Node
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto const node = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(
    "moveit_simple",
    rclcpp::NodeOptions().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true)
  );

  auto const logger = rclcpp::get_logger("moveit_simple");

  // Create the MoveIt MoveGroup Interface
using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface;
auto move_group_interface = MoveGroupInterface(node, "ur_manipulator");

// Set a target Pose
  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose target_pose;
  target_pose.orientation.x = 1.0;
  target_pose.orientation.y = 0.00;
  target_pose.orientation.z = 0.00;
  target_pose.orientation.w = 0.00;
  target_pose.position.x = 0.343;
  target_pose.position.y = 0.132;
  target_pose.position.z = 0.264;
move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(target_pose);

  success_arm = (move_group_arm.plan(my_plan_arm) ==
                 moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);

  move_group_interface.execute(my_plan_arm);

  std::vector<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose> approach_waypoints;
  target_pose.position.y -= 0.01;
  approach_waypoints.push_back(target_pose);

  target_pose.position.y -= 0.01;
  approach_waypoints.push_back(target_pose);

  moveit_msgs::msg::RobotTrajectory trajectory_approach;
  const double jump_threshold = 0.0;
  const double eef_step = 0.01;

  double fraction = move_group_arm.computeCartesianPath(
      approach_waypoints, eef_step, jump_threshold, trajectory_approach);

  move_group_arm.execute(trajectory_approach);

  // Shutdown ROS
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

